# Count repeated items in an observableArray in knockout js

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

i have an observableArray with about 540 records

in the records it has an advert property and a date property i would like to do a function that finds all the adverts with on a particular date and counts the number of records eg

Date = 23/02/2015

1. Advert 1 (16)
2. Advert 2 (5)
3. Advert 3 (10)

Total (31)

Comment: Can you post (an excerpt of) your viewmodel, so we can see what your records look like?  It will help to craft the answer, rather than it being quite generic.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Knockout question.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/simon1709/g3suk2ch/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get along, but basically you can have a function that iterates through the object and creates an array of counts:

```
self.counts = ko.observable();

function updateCounts() {
    var leads = self.leads(),
        counts = {};

    for (var i = 0, j = leads.length; i < j; i++) {
        var prop = leads[i].date_enquired();

        if (counts[prop] == null) {
            counts[prop] = {
                name  : prop,
                count : 1
            };
        }
        else {
            counts[prop].count++;
        }
    }

    // set it as an array instead of an object
    self.counts(Object.keys(counts).map(function (key) { return counts[key]; }));
}
```

Run this function at the start and whenever the list updates:

```
updateCounts();
self.leads.subscribe(updateCounts);
```

Then display the object in the view in whatever way you'd like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: counts">
    <div data-bind="text: name + ': ' + count"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3suk2ch/3/)

You could also create your own object that handles pushing to the array and updating the list of counts. That way additions are `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` each time an item is added or removed. Overall, it's not too big of a deal because iterating over 500 items is really fast.